# Where to apply binomial expansion?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, applications

I would like to know where I could apply the expression as part of other equation

$$\bigg( 1 + \frac{x}{r} \bigg)^r$$

considering $r \in Z$. It means, in what kind of problem I can use this expression.

For me, it does not matter the number $r$. For example, when $r \to \infty$ it becomes $exp(x)$ which can be used in lots of engineering problems

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking.  Clearly small values or $r$ give different results: e.g. $1+x \not=e^x$ for non-zero $x$

Comment: In which math, physical or engineering models I can find such expression?

Comment: See [compound interest formula](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/financial/compound-interest-calculator.php)